# Beta distributed variable standard deviation and mean

Tags: descriptive-statistics, beta-distribution, beta-regression

I'm new to beta regression and I'm trying to figure out what the appropriate descriptives are to report when you have a beta-distributed variable. If I have a two-level IV predicting a beta-distributed DV, how should I calculate the descriptives for the two conditions? Or should I report something other than mean and standard deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have a straightforward two-sample problem then I would use a visualization rather than a table of numeric statistics, e.g., histograms of both subsamples with the fitted beta density superimposed.